# Why doesn't $\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^n=-1$?

Tags: summation, binary, convention

Now of course I'm not stranger to the fact that adding finite (and in many cases - infinite) amount of positive numbers always yeilds a positive number, but in many cases, often the finite limit isn't equivalent to the strange nature of infinity. It seems that mathematics tends to prefer that if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^n$ were to converge, it likes

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^n=-1$$

This can be seen in many "proofs" like forcing the geometric series formula:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n=\frac{1}{1-r}\implies\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^n=\frac{1}{1-2}=-1$$

Or the digit function (which returns the digit in the $b^n$ column of $x$ in base $b$):

$$D_b^n(x)=\lfloor\frac{x}{b^n}\rfloor-b\lfloor\frac{x}{b^{n+1}}\rfloor$$

(E.g; $D_{10}^{-2}(\pi)=4$)

For $-1$:
$$D_2^n(-1)=1 \forall n>0$$
$$D_2^n(-1)=0 \forall n\leq0$$

Hence it could be seen that $-1_{(10)}=\bar1.0_{(2)}$, which implies $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^n=-1$$

> Besides conventions for convergence, what exactly is stopping this sum from being equal to $-1$? Would such an equivalence lead to a contradiction?

Computationally concerned, using $-1_{(10)}=\bar1.0_{(2)}$ as a binary expansion holds all the expected arithmetic properties like $\bar1.0_{(2)}\times\bar1.0_{(2)}=\bar01.0_{(2)}$

Comment: I hate asking this but could someone explain the downvotes? I am simply curious about the conventions of convergence of infinite sums, and it seems to me this question is relevant from a theoretical standpoint surrounding such.

Comment: In the $2$-adic numbers, it's true. But not over $\Bbb R$ nor over the $p$-adics for odd $p$.

Comment: Whether it does [depends on the norm in your definition of a limit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XFDM1ip5HdU).

Comment: This looks quite similar: [Why does an argument similiar to 0.999...=1 show 999...=-1?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1623917/42969)

Comment: Or this: [The sum of powers of two and two's complement – is there a deeper meaning behind this?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/174768/42969).

Comment: Also: [Sum of non negative powers of 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/284283/42969)

Comment: @MartinR Thank you, very insightful. Glad I'm not the only crazy one.

Comment: @Graviton, downvotes without Comments will be a mystery. Anyway, probably you should have limited your context to real numbers as Angina Seng pointed out. Also, that summation formula you used is meant for infinite series having $|r|<1$. So it's wrong to use it in the first place. That's all I can say in the scope of my knowledge.

Comment: @MartinR This is not similar. $0.\bar 9=1$ is the consequence of a convergent series $0.9+0.09+0.009+\cdots=1$ , but $1+2+4+\cdots $ is not converging , at least not in the real numbers. The downvotes are surely because people are sick of "regularizations" like $1+2+3+\cdots =-1/12$. The "equality" here is based on a very similar idea. If $2$-adic numbers are meant, this must be explicitely mentioned.

Comment: @Peter Thanks Peter, that makes sense. As an undergrad I had no idea what $p$-adic numbers were until this a few moments ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n$$ converges, then it converges to $-1$

is a true statement.

So is the statement

> If $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n$$ converges, then it converges to $42$.

And so is the statement

> If $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n$$ converges, then the Earth is flat.

---

All three statements are true because $A\implies B$ is always true if $A$ is false. The simple fact is that the expression $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n$$ denotes the sum of a **divergent** series, and it therefore cannot be used in an equality because it is undefined.

The expression $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$$ is simply shorthand for $$\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=0}^Na_n.$$

If you plug in $a_n=2^n$ into that expression, you see that what you are really asking is why

$$\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=0}^N 2^n=-1$$ is not true. And it is not true because the right-hand side of the equality is a real number, while the left hand side is an undefined expression.

Comment: I understand, so it is not equal because of the convention that an infinite summation is equal to it's limit?

Comment: However I'm just not sure that $-1=\bar1_{(2)}$ being true actually leads to a contradiction outside of this convention.

Comment: @Graviton That's not a convention, that's a definition.

Comment: Indeed, though a definition that is conventionally accepted.

Comment: @Graviton If the equality were true, then a **false** statement is true. That is in itself a contradiction. Further, as I said, if that statement is true, then **all** statements are true. Let's say $A$ is the statement $-1=\sum_{i=0}^\infty$. Now, take any statement $p$. Then, the statement $A\implies p$ is true, because $A$ is false. But also, we have that $A$ is true, and $A\implies p$ is true, so, by modus ponens, $p$ is true. QED. Even if $p$ is "the moon is made of cheese", we managed to prove $p$.

Comment: I am quite aware of the principle of explosion, I just do not believe outside that definition for an infinite sum,  $(\top\implies(-1=\bar1_{(2)}))$ is false.

Comment: @Graviton What do you mean by "outside that definition"? Are we throwing away that definition then? If so, what do we replace it with? What does the expression $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n$$ even **mean**, if we just discarded the definition? It's now just a bunch of symbols with no more meaning behind it than a flat Earther congress.

Comment: I imagine it would depend if by $\infty$ one is referring to $\omega$ or some other strictly defined infinity. The use of $\infty$ there is meaningless without specification of which infinity.

Comment: "The use of $\infty$ there"... Where? In the summation sign? That symbol a part of a strictly defined symbol. The collection of symbols $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$$ is defined as $$\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^N a_n.$$ Further, the collection of symbols $$\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n$$ is defined as the value $L\in\mathbb R$ for which the following statement is true:

$$\forall\epsilon > 0\exists N_0\in\mathbb N: n>N_0\implies |L-b_n|<\epsilon.$$

All symbols in the statement are again strictly defined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110894/discussion-between-graviton-and-5xum).